# Library to wrap notify-send

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a library and two related scripts to wrap `notify-send` from `libnotify`.
I need this script, since I am remotely administering workstations and wanted to automate desktop messages.
Since `notify-send` needs a DBUS session address configured in the environment variables and to be run within the context of the user the notification is sent to, I chose an implementation in python 3.6, since a previous shellscript became too complex and unstable.

So [here](https://gitlab.com/coNQP/notify-users) is what I came up with:

```
#    usernotify - Wrapper library for notify-send.
#    Copyright (C) 2018  Richard Neumann
#
#    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#    GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
"""A notify-send wrapping library."""

from configparser import Error, ConfigParser
from logging import basicConfig, getLogger
from os import setuid, fork, wait, _exit, environ
from pathlib import Path
from pwd import getpwnam
from subprocess import call


__all__ = ['MIN_UID', 'MAX_UID', 'send', 'broadcast', 'Args']

_LOG_FORMAT = '[%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
basicConfig(format=_LOG_FORMAT)
_LOGGER = getLogger(__file__)
_DBUS_ENV_VAR = 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'
_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'MIN_UID': 1000,
    'MAX_UID': 60000,
    'NOTIFY_SEND': '/usr/bin/notify-send',
    'RUN_USER': '/run/user'}
_SECTION_NAME = 'UserNotify'

# Load global configurations.
_CONFIG = ConfigParser()
_CONFIG.setdefault(_SECTION_NAME, _DEFAULT_CONFIG)
_CONFIG_PATH = Path('/etc/usernotify.conf')

try:
    _CONFIG.read(_CONFIG_PATH)
except Error as error:
    _LOGGER.warning(error)

# Load user-dependent configuration.
_USER_CONFIG = ConfigParser()
_USER_CONFIG_PATH = Path.home().joinpath('.usernotify.conf')

try:
    _USER_CONFIG.read(_USER_CONFIG_PATH)
except Error as error:
    _LOGGER.warning(error)

_CONFIG.update(_USER_CONFIG)
_SECTION = _CONFIG[_SECTION_NAME]

# Read configuration values.
MIN_UID = int(_SECTION['MIN_UID'])
MAX_UID = int(_SECTION['MAX_UID'])
_NOTIFY_SEND = _SECTION['NOTIFY_SEND']
_RUN_USER = Path(_SECTION['RUN_USER'])
_DBUS_BUS_DIR = '{}/bus'
_DBUS_PATH = _RUN_USER.joinpath(_DBUS_BUS_DIR)
_DBUS_BUS_GLOB = _DBUS_BUS_DIR.format('*')
_DBUS_ENV_PATH = f'unix:path={_DBUS_PATH}'
_UIDS = range(MIN_UID, MAX_UID + 1)


def _getuid(user):
    """Gets the UID for the respective user."""

    try:
        return int(user)
    except ValueError:
        return getpwnam(user).pw_uid


def send(user, args):
    """Sends a notification to the respective user."""

    uid = _getuid(user)
    env = {_DBUS_ENV_VAR: _DBUS_ENV_PATH.format(uid)}
    command = (_NOTIFY_SEND,) + tuple(args)

    if fork() == 0:
        setuid(uid)

        with _Env(env):
            exit_code = call(command)
            _exit(exit_code)

    _, returncode = wait()
    return returncode


def broadcast(args, uids=_UIDS):
    """Seds the respective message to all
    users with an active DBUS session.
    """

    returncode = 0

    for path in _RUN_USER.glob(_DBUS_BUS_GLOB):
        uid = int(path.parent.name)

        if uid in uids:
            returncode += send(uid, args)

    return returncode


class _Env:
    """Context manager to temporarily substitute environment variables."""

    __slots__ = ('env', 'substituted')

    def __init__(self, env):
        """Sets the dict of evironment variables to substitute."""
        self.env = env
        self.substituted = {}

    def __enter__(self):
        """Substitutes the evironment variables."""
        for key in self.env:
            self.substituted[key] = environ.get(key)

        environ.update(self.env)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        """Restores the substituted environment variables."""
        for key, value in self.substituted.items():
            if value is None:
                del environ[key]
            else:
                environ[key] = value

        self.substituted.clear()


class Args:
    """Arguments for nofiy-send."""

    __slots__ = (
        'summary', 'body', 'urgency', 'expire_time', 'app_name', 'icon',
        'category', 'hint', 'version')

    def __init__(self, summary, body=None, urgency=None, expire_time=None,
                 app_name=None, icon=None, category=None, hint=None,
                 version=None):
        """Initailizes the arguments."""
        self.summary = summary
        self.body = body
        self.urgency = urgency
        self.expire_time = expire_time
        self.app_name = app_name
        self.icon = icon
        self.category = category
        self.hint = hint
        self.version = version

    @classmethod
    def from_options(cls, options):
        """Creates arguments from the respective docopt options."""
        return cls(
            options['<summary>'],
            body=options['<body>'],
            urgency=options['--urgency'],
            expire_time=options['--expire-time'],
            app_name=options['--app-name'],
            icon=options['--icon'],
            category=options['--category'],
            hint=options['--hint'],
            version=options['--version'])

    def __iter__(self):
        """Yields the command line arguments for notify-send."""
        if self.urgency is not None:
            yield '--urgency'
            yield self.urgency

        if self.expire_time is not None:
            yield '--expire-time'
            yield self.expire_time

        if self.app_name is not None:
            yield '--app-name'
            yield self.app_name

        if self.icon is not None:
            yield '--icon'
            yield self.icon

        if self.category is not None:
            yield '--category'
            yield self.category

        if self.hint is not None:
            yield '--hint'
            yield self.hint

        if self.version:    # Bool.
            yield '--version'

        yield self.summary

        if self.body is not None:
            yield self.body
```

While the library is working perfectly fine, I'd prefer a more elegant way to *temporarily* substitute the user context instead of doing a fork (or worse using `su` in the subprocess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Python >= 3.5, you sould use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) that superseeds the [older high-level API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio). Doing so, you would be able to use the `env` keyword to provide the new environment for the child process; letting you get rid of the `_Env` class completely:

```
def send(user, args):
    """Sends a notification to the respective user."""

    uid = _getuid(user)
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env[_DBUS_ENV_VAR] = _DBUS_ENV_PATH.format(uid)
    command = (_NOTIFY_SEND,) + tuple(args)

    if fork() == 0:
        setuid(uid)

        exit_code = subprocess.run(command, env=env).returncode
        _exit(exit_code)

    _, returncode = wait()
    return returncode
```

However manually forking to call `setuid` doesn't feel quite right either; especially since subprocess will fork itself. And I don't talk about the way the child return code is returned to the caller… There have to be something easier.

The [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor exposes a `preexec_fn` parameter that will do exactly that: after the `fork` and before the child `exec`, `preexec_fn` will by called by the child process. Let's put that to good use:

```
def send(user, args):
    """Sends a notification to the respective user."""

    uid = _getuid(user)
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env[_DBUS_ENV_VAR] = _DBUS_ENV_PATH.format(uid)
    command = (_NOTIFY_SEND,) + tuple(args)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, env=env, preexec_fn=lambda: setuid(uid))
    return proc.wait()
```

Lastly, you can build the `command` by unpacking the generator directly rather than combining tuples:

```
def send(user, args):
    """Sends a notification to the respective user."""

    uid = _getuid(user)
    env = os.environ.copy()
    env[_DBUS_ENV_VAR] = _DBUS_ENV_PATH.format(uid)
    command = (_NOTIFY_SEND, *args)

    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, env=env, preexec_fn=lambda: setuid(uid))
    return proc.wait()
```

However, since `send` is called in a `for` loop with exactly the same `args` each time, it might be a good idea to unroll that call to avoid duplicated work:

```
def broadcast(args, uids=_UIDS):
    """Sends the respective message to all
    users with an active DBUS session.
    """

    returncode = 0
    env = os.environ.copy()
    command = (_NOTIFY_SEND, *args)

    for path in _RUN_USER.glob(_DBUS_BUS_GLOB):
        uid = int(path.parent.name)

        if uid in uids:
            env[_DBUS_ENV_VAR] = _DBUS_ENV_PATH.format(uid)

            proc = subprocess.Popen(command, env=env, preexec_fn=lambda: setuid(uid))
            returncode += proc.wait()

    return returncode
```